# Assert in for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, pytest, assert, allure

I have a list of variables which I have to assert to 0. now the code has to be a part of **pytest** framework & compatible with allure reporting. Since the assert I use declares only 1 test case is there anyway I check every assert as a diff **scn**?

```
list = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
for x in list:
    assert x == 0
```

When I run the above code it passes off as 1 test case. Is there any other way rather than specifying each element, to have **allure/pytest** treat each assert as a diff test case?

Comment: Why do you want to treat each assertion as a separate test case?

Comment: I think that `subTest` is able to give you a different report for each assert.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html?

Comment: Don't overwrite python builtin keywords/functions such as `list` unless you know what you're doing. It can/will cause issues down the line, along with being poor variable naming.

Comment: @Jab the list word was just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1** Here is the solution for you question

```
import pytest

list = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
@pytest.mark.nondestructive
@pytest.mark.parametrize("item",list)
def test_stackquestion(item):
    assert item == 0
```

**Option 2** if you want to get the result within one test and don't want the test to terminate after each assert and gives collective result of all the asserts you can implement soft assert using [delayed assert](https://pypi.org/project/delayed-assert/) too.